# Woocommerce, не выводится цена

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Почему не выводятся цены товаров? Установлена тема The gem.
Сделал импорт тестовых товаров из файла `sample_products.csv`, но на странице товаров цены отсутствуют, только название товара и картинка товара есть.
Проверял на чистом `wordpress`, т.е. без темы, импортировал такие же товары, цены есть.
Из-за чего это может быть? Как вывести цены?
Версия woocommerce - 3.4.7
разметка отдельного товара:

```
<div class="inline-column col-sm-3 col-xs-6 catalog-view post-31792 product type-product status-publish has-post-thumbnail product_cat-audioknigi last instock sale shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple">
    <div class="product-inner centered-box">
        <a href="http://site.com/product/tovar1/" class="product-image">
            <div class="product-labels">
                <span class="onsale title-h6">Распродажа!</span>
            </div>
            <span class="product-image-inner">
                <img width="300" height="300" src="http://site.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/tovar1-300x300.jpg"
                       class="attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail size-woocommerce_thumbnail wp-post-image"
                       alt="" srcset="http://site.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/tovar1-300x300.jpg 300w, http://site.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/tovar1-150x150.jpg 150w, http://site.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/tovar1-256x256.jpg 256w, http://site.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/tovar1-100x100.jpg 100w"
                                                   sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px">
                <span class="woo-product-overlay"></span></span>
        </a>

        <div class="product-info clearfix">
            <div class="product-rating product-rating-empty">
                <div class="empty-rating"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="product-title title-h6"><a href="http://site.com/product/tovar1/">Товар1</a></div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ну так -то тяжело наверное ответить на ваш вопрос, по коду вообще ничего нет, а по сути нужно смотреть в чем у вас конкретно проблема

Comment: проблема решена, нужно было в настройках темы включить чекбокс, там есть одна настройка, касающаяся woocommerce

Comment: Режим каталога наверное был включен